# access control value in all rows GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have an template field in a GridView :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-field small" ID="txtPhoneNo" Text="" EnableViewState="true"
                    runat="server" />
                >
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

I wrote this code to access textbox value in rows :

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in grvPhoneType.Rows) {
    string  PhoneNumber = (((row.FindControl("txtPhoneNo")) as TextBox).Text);
    // Do what ever with PhoneNumber 

}
```

although user enters value  on txtPhoneNo textbox but variable PhoneNumber is empty.
What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the FindConrol method in the cell that holds the control.  The following example would work if your template column is the first column in your GridView.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in grvPhoneType.Rows) {
 string  PhoneNumber = (((row.cells(0).FindControl("txtPhoneNo")) as TextBox).Text);
 // Do what ever with PhoneNumber
   }
```

Comment: Are you doing anything with the GridView on the PostBack that would be rerendering or clearing the values of Textboxes?